# 2011 f150 ecoboost timing chain and valve train

Tags: ford, f-150, timing, timing-chain

Looking to find the book rate for how many hours labour to change full timing set including vct's, chains and intake cams 3.5l ecoboost

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Mitchell shows 12.3 hours for the timing set and an additional 1.6 hours to R&R the cams on both banks. Probably add a half hour to R&R the vct solenoids. The actuators are figured into the 12.3 figure.

Answer (score 1):

Alldata says 10.8 for the cams (but all four), and figure another 2.5 for the timing chain and guides/tensioners.  I doubt you need VCT solenoids, but the actuators won't add much (maybe an hour) if you are already replacing cams.

So Ben's answer totals about 14.4, my estimate (Alldata) suggests around 14.3 maybe an hour or more less if the exhaust cams stay put.

Either way . . .  **OUCH**

Better luck.

Comment: Doesn’t sound any worse than a v8 triton lol.

Comment: @Ben Certainly not, especially after you leave half the spark plug threads in the head...